# sshpass not working: permision denied

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I'm trying to log into my machine via SSHPASS but it always gives me permission denied.

I can connect via PUTTY or via standard SSH command, but i want to creat automatic script which will connect to all my machines with ssh and do some stuff so i need SSHPASS because you can write password into command.

I am using special characters in my password as you can see in LOG. (of course this is not my password, but i do use characters: $ . )

LOG:

```
root@emanuel:/home/emanuel# sshpass -p "$1$vXc7$lXQA6fy." ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@192.168.1.149
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.149 [192.168.1.149] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.149:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qp+iUWXCwGG8Fq83vfqFJKI/VbAlSF9Y5RInrT5ywO8
debug1: Host '192.168.1.149' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: You should really be using public key authentication, it's [not that hard to set up](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and then you can connect without using a password.

Comment: yes i know, but i am in situation that i have hundred machines and i cant go from one to another for setting up keys and copy it to server :( thank you for your suggestion

Comment: You are getting permission denied, because of your password is wrong or the account is locked. Can you login while typing the password manually? Update the question with more verbose debug log (with `-vvv`).